# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED', error with Selenium+python+browsermobproxy

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I am automating my web application with Selenium on Chrome browser. I am using `browsermob-proxy==0.8.0` python package to capture HAR file.

I am getting the below errors intermittently. Can someone please help me on this?

The console log shows this error -

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED'
```

[No internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jYZo.png)

Comment: are you able to connect manually to that website when proxy is enabled ?

Comment: yes.Selenium also able to connect and run the scrips and record the HAR file. But, sometimes, it fails in mid of execution due to this error. Sometimes, I get an error screenshot of 'No Internet' with a message saying 'There is something wrong with the proxy server or the address is incorrect. 'ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED'